# Clear Tuple in Python after For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples, mysql-python

I am struggling to figure out how to clear out the tuple 'data' after reading from a database.

**Process Flow:**

Every X minutes, I call batchUpdate

batchUpdate pulls in records matching a certain condition

We iterate through those records performing updates

The process ends and waits for the next call

**Issue:**

Every subsequent call to the function batchUpdate results in no new data. The tuple 'data' contains the same values as before.

**Simplified Example (only pulling one record, scheduled every 1 second):**

```
Update has started
((10938L, u"@anonymized @anonymized House of Cards will be nothing compared  to the Drumpf's!And worst of all is that Americans chose him as president?", u'New York, USA'),)
Update has started
((10938L, u"@anonymized @anonymized House of Cards will be nothing compared to the Drumpf's!And worst of all is that Americans chose him as president?", u'New York, USA'),)
Update has started
((10938L, u"@anonymized @anonymized House of Cards will be nothing compared to the Drumpf's!And worst of all is that Americans chose him as president?", u'New York, USA'),)
Update has started
((10938L, u"@anonymized @anonymized House of Cards will be nothing compared to the Drumpf's!And worst of all is that Americans chose him as president?", u'New York, USA'),)
```

**Code:**

```
class analyzeRecords():
    def batchUpdate(self):

     global data

     #Select up to 1 record

     b.execute(""" SELECT id, tweet,tweet_location_guess FROM rawTweets where compoundScore IS NULL LIMIT 0,1 """)

     #Put that data into a tuple

     data = b.fetchall()

     print(data)

     #print that update has started

     print("Update has started")

     for row in data:
          idMatch = row[0]
          cleanTweet = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, d[y]), sorted(d, key=lambda i: len(i), reverse=True), row[1].lower())
          sentimentScores = analyzer.polarity_scores(cleanTweet)
          overallScore = sentimentScores["compound"]

          u.execute("""UPDATE rawTweets SET tweet=%s, compoundScore=%s where id=%s""",
                    (cleanTweet, overallScore, idMatch))
          update.commit()

l = task.LoopingCall(analyzeRecords().batchUpdate)
l.start(timeout) # call every sixty seconds

reactor.run()
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding. Could you simply set `data = None` at the end of your function?

Comment: But `b.execute` returns different data? Is there any reason to define data as global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are executing these two lines:

```
 global data

 data = b.fetchall()
```

Taken together, these two statements should overwrite whatever was in the `data` variable previously.

I'll point out that this function doesn't appear to *need* a global variable - you can, and probably should, just use a local variable for this.

Regardless, I don't think the problem is that there is some mysterious leftover data, unless the `b.fetchall()` object is defined to do that. (For example, if there is an error in your query, or your query returns no matches, how does it communicate that? If it raises, or returns a value that you are ignoring, perhaps `fetchall` might be returning stale data because you were supposed to check the value and not call fetchall...)

I suggest that you look at how `execute` and `fetchall` work together, and also look at your for loop. I see `b.execute` and `u.execute` and `update.commit`. That seems like you have many different database connections. Maybe you do. Or maybe you copy/pasted code, and you really should be doing something like:

```
u.execute(...)
u.commit()
```

Comment: I was stupid with the database connection / cursor.  Problem resolved.

Thanks!